# Importing a Class from another python file in Vscode

Tags: python-3.x, class, visual-studio-code

I have made this class in python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Post():
     def __init__(self):
        self.title="this is my title"
        self.content= "this is some content"
        self.author= "Ata"
```

And then wanted to import this class into another file named "app.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# importing class from post.py into app.py
from post import Post
post= Post()
post2= Post()

print (post.content)
```

but get this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'Post'

what is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got my answer... The only thing that I had to do in order to import my class into another python file  was that I should have saved it. that's all and after this everything works fine.